# MySQL Error Code 1452 Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1452

I'm receiving an error when I attempt to create two tables.  There was a multivalued dependency, so I separated the tables and came up with this:

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (
NameID      Integer             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name        varChar(255)        NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  NAME_PK             PRIMARY KEY(NameID)
);

CREATE TABLE PHONE (
NameID      Integer             NOT NULL,
PhoneNumber varChar(15)         NOT NULL,
NumType     varChar(5)          NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  PHONE_FK            FOREIGN KEY(NameID)
    REFERENCES NAME(NameID),
CONSTRAINT  PHONE_PK            PRIMARY KEY(NameID)
);
```

But when attempting to add values with this code:

```
INSERT INTO NAME (NameID, Name) VALUES (default, 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO PHONE (NameID, PhoneNumber, NumType) VALUES (default, '706-782-4719', 'Home');
```

I receive the infamous 1452 error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`phone_mcneill`.`PHONE`, CONSTRAINT `PHONE_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`NameID`) REFERENCES `NAME` (`NameID`))
```

I am not entirely sure what this means as I have NameID autoincrementing in the first table.  I can't have it auto_increment in the second one as well as it's a foreign key, correct?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined a foreign key constraint on `NameID` column i.e in table `PHONE` using insert for phone table you have passed default against NameID ,but NameID is pointing to `NAME` table and expecting to have the inserted record id from `NAME` table it doesn't have a default value  as per the docs

> When a new AUTO_INCREMENT value has been generated, you can also
>   obtain it by executing a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

So your second insert can use the inserted if from `NAME` table like

```
INSERT INTO NAME (NameID, NAME) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO PHONE (NameID, PhoneNumber, NumType) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '706-782-4719', 'Home');
```

And you can grab results from both tables  by joining them

```
select * from NAME
JOIN PHONE 
USING (NameID)
```

[**How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

[**See fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c8af/1)