# SQL insert into multiples tables

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I want to do an insert on two tables, one value of the second table field is the value of one field on the first table. The problem is: this value is AutoIncrement and is generated when the insert in the table. So how can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: "how can i do it?" - by posting details and making an attempt.

Comment: pravinS why do you asume PHP ?

Comment: [**LAST_INSERT_ID() Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2050b/1) for reference see [*MySQL Error Code 1452 Foreign Key Constraint*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210461/mysql-error-code-1452-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Quote:

> if you want to use the ID that was generated for one table and insert
>   it into a second table, you can use SQL statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table
```