# Cannot add foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

Here is the statement I am executing and related error, any hints what is wrong and how to debug further is appreciated. Using MySQL Workbench/MySQL.

Especially confused what means child row here? How foreign key related to child row? And what is the child row here?

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Customer FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) 
REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`test`.`#sql-ff_2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Customer` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES `Customers` (`CustomerID`))

Comment: might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210461/mysql-error-code-1452-foreign-key-constraint) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa) help?

Comment: @KevinEsche, my issue happens when define foreign key constraint, and the issue you referred to is dealing with errors during insert? Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: check out the second link, be sure that all ids you are trying to refer to are existing in the refering table aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that your tables contain data that should not be allowed by the foreign key you're trying to create. You could use a query to find them:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orders
WHERE  customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid FROM customers)
```

If you're sure these rows are indeed faulty, you could use a similar `delete` statement to remove them:

```
DELETE FROM orders
WHERE  customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid FROM customers)
```

Comment: thanks and met with error, Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE customerID NOT IN (SELECT customerid FROM Orders)' at line 2

Comment: @LinMa on which statement? the `select` or the `delete`?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, for delete statement.

Comment: @LinMa for some reason I missed the `from` keyword. Fixed - please see my updated answer.